# How to extract 4 characters between '(' and '@'

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a text file in this format:

```
((abcd@04548_5957:0.0363,(((efgh@00512_777:0.019251010,((igkl@03175_4509:0.01768455)100:((efgh@0.05985636)57:
```

How can I extract only 4 characters before the `@` mark, and if the strings repeat in the file, give the number as well? Like

```
abcd 1
efgh 2
igkl 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- Any 4 characters preceding a `@` constitute a match.
- Sorting the matches is acceptable.

With *GNU* `grep`:

```
grep -Po '.{4}(?=@)' file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'
```

- `-o` instructs `grep` to only output the *matching parts* of each line.
  GNU `grep`'s `-P` option enables support for [PCREs](http://www.pcre.org/), which support look-around assertions (among other features); in this case, they allow use of positive look-ahead assertion `(?=@)` to *detect* `@` without including it in the match.
- `uniq -c` takes the `sort`ed input and folds adjacent lines with the same content into a single line preceded by their count, separated with a space.
- `awk '{ print $2, $1 }'` simply swaps the two output columns to place the match before the count.

(More robust alternative that matches between `(` and `@`:

```
grep -Po '\(+\K.*?(?=@)' file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'
```

)

With *BSD/macOS* `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '.{4}@' file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print substr($2, 1, length($2)-1), $1 }'
```

[Only needed with *BSD/macOS* `grep`] Conceptually slightly simpler variants (albeit slightly less efficient), as suggested by [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) :

```
grep -Eo '.{4}@' file | tr -d @ | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'
grep -Eo '.{4}@' file | sed 's/@$//' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2, $1 }'
```

Comment: If sorting is not important, the whole `sort|uniq|awk`-pipeline can be replaced by a faster `awk '{a[$0]++} END {for (k in a) print k, a[k]}'`

Comment: @Dario: Good point, but then you might as well go for William Pursell's `awk`-only solution.

Comment: Using the grep commands by @mklement0 gave me correct numbers. For some reason the awk solution didn't output all situations.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'length($1)==4{count[$1]++}
    END{for(i in count) print i": "count[i]}
' RS=\( FS=@ input-file
```

By setting RS to `(`, and FS to `@`, awk takes the text between `(` and `@` as the first field of each record.  If that field has length 4, we increment a counter in the array `count`.  At the end, we simply print out all of the counts.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F@ '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) a[substr($i,length($i)-3)]++} 
       END {for(k in a) print k, a[k]}' file

abcd 1
igkl 1
efgh 2
```